# error when creating channel with kafka ordering service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to setup hyperledger fabric 1.2 on different hosts.
But when creating channel via: ./peer.sh channel create -o orderer0.trade.com:7050 -c tradechannel -f ../tradechannel.tx --cafile tlsca.trade.com-cert.pem -t 150s.
I got this error in CLI: *got unexpected status: SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE -- will not enqueue, consenter for this channel hasn't started yet*

and here is log from orderer:
*[channel: tradechannel] Rejecting broadcast of message from 192.168.167.149:60655 with SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE: rejected by Consenter: will not enqueue, consenter for this channel hasn't started yet.
Closing Broadcast stream
transport: http2Server.HandleStreams failed to read frame: read tcp 192.168.171.33:7050->192.168.167.149:60655: read: connection reset by peer*

It seems I have problem with grpc but totally have no idea about this.
the CLI is in Macbook and Orderer runs in RedHat.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue when I was spawning the hyperledger fabric on **kubernetes** using **kafka as ordering service**.

The error is coming because k**afka need some to sync with zookeeper**s. So you can wait for some time after the blockchain network creation. Then create the channel. In my case I wait for 10 minutes and I am able to create a channel.

But when I am spawning the fabric network using docker and kafka as ordering service this error never occurs and in this case kafka synchronise with zookeepers very fast, I don't why no error "rejected by Consenter: will not enqueue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRGXd.png)".